# find the particular solution of $2y''-y'=-x+1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried setting $y_p = Ax+B$ but it failed. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y=1$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $2y'' - y' = 0$, while $y=x$ is not.  Therefore you should increase the degree of the polynomial by $1$ and remove the constant term: try $y = a x^2 + b x$.

Comment: thank you. so for a lot of these questions you just need to keep increasing your order?

Comment: Basically yes.  See e.g. [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/undcoef/undcoef.html)